# IllegalArgumentException on orientation change using different layouts for landscape & portrait

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-view, android-orientation

I have a `Fragment` which uses different layouts in landscape and portrait orientation. In landscape mode, the root element is a `LinearLayout`, while in portrait mode it is a `ScrollLayout`:

**res/layout/fragment.xml**

```
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".NewBathingSiteFragment"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_new_bathing_site"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/nbs_scrollView">

....
```

**res/layout-land/fragment.xml**

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".NewBathingSiteFragment"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_new_bathing_site"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/nbs_linearLayout">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/nbs_scrollView">


    ...
```

I'm getting this error on orientation change:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Wrong state class, expecting View State but 
   received class android.widget.ScrollView$SavedState instead. This usually 
   happens when two views of different type have the same id in the same hierarchy. 
   This view's id is id/newBathingSiteFragment. Make sure other views do not use 
   the same id.
```

No two views have the same ID in the same layout (they do have the same ID in the two different layouts, because I need to find them using `findViewById()`). The ID `newBathingSiteFragment` is the ID for the `Fragment`, and is set in XML in the activity layout.

I was able to make the problem go away by adding a `LinearLayout` as the root element for portrait mode as well, making the structure identical to landscape mode (except that in landscape mode there is one more view in the `LinearLayout` displaying next to the `ScrollView`).

Is this the preferred solution to this? Or is there a better way, without adding an "unnecessary" `LinearLayout` to portrait mode?

Comment: You said no views have same ID? But you have `android:id="@+id/nbs_scrollView"` in your Portrait and `android:id="@+id/nbs_scrollView"` in your landscape. In any case, it is always good to keep these IDs the same and only place them in separate `res/layout` folders - like `res/layout-land` (landscape) or `res/layout-port` (portrait).

Comment: That's exactly what I'm doing.

Comment: OK, noted. Usually if you have same IDs and the layout changes into something else in a different orientation (`two views of different type have the same id`), the `Wrong state class ..` error pops up - but this does not seem to have been the case here? Can you show us the complete layouts (before you added the LinearLayout part) - just want to see how you used the `newBathingSiteFragment ` ID.

Comment: One other item to take a look at is if you are inflating layouts in multiple configurations/orientations into a `ViewStub` with an `android:inflatedId`. If different views are being inflated per configuration/orientation, you'll end up with multiple views of different type sharing the same view id.